# .all.length vs .length in before_create - crazy behavior!? Can someone explain this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've solved my problem but I have 0 ideas why this is occurring, is this a weird bug?

I have a before create action in my memberships model.

Memberships can belong_to an organization.  Organization has_many memberships.

`before_create :check_payment_plan`

Then I have some logic in the check_payment_plan method.  What it does is irrelevant.  As I've found the following behavior:

When the method looks like:

```
def check_payment_plan
     puts self.organization.memberships.length
end

**The membership is not created.**
```

When the method looks like:

```
def check_payment_plan
     puts self.organization.memberships.all.length
end

**The membership is created.**
```

So for future reference if someone is having instances of a model not being created in a before_filter check that if the above pattern is followed, .all.length is utilized.

Can anyone explain why this is occurring?!

Comment: What do you mean by `**The membership is not created.**` what are you doing on basis of ` self.organization.memberships.length`?

Comment: How does count/length create a model?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually simplify that to be `self.organization.memberships.count` which lets the count happen at the DB level, which may solve the issue you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that the Model is just representative of a single instance not all of them. Which is why you must call .all first.